# Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use addresses.set() instead

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am going to create and update nested relationships but it is not working as expected I have a three models User, Profile and Address. Profile model is a FK in Address model

**profiles/models.py**

```
class Address(models.Model):
   profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, related_name='addresses', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   address = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

**profiels/serializers.py**

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    addresses = AddressSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Profile
    fields = ['gender', 'date_of_birth', 'hometown', 'phone', 'addresses']

def create(self, validated_data):
    addresses_data = validated_data.pop('addresses')
    profile = Profile.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for address_data in addresses_data:
        Address.objects.create(profile=profile, **address_data)
    return profile
```

**users/serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
profile = ProfileSerializer(required=True)
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['id', 'url', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'profile']
    extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

def create(self, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    password = validated_data.pop('password')
    user = User(**validated_data)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    Profile.objects.create(user=user, **profile_data)
    return user

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
    profile = instance.profile
    instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
    instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
    instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
    instance.save()

    profile.gender = profile_data.get('gender', profile.gender)
    profile.date_of_birth = profile_data.get('date_of_birth', profile.date_of_birth)
    profile.hometown = profile_data.get('hometown', profile.hometown)
    profile.phone = profile_data.get('phone', profile.phone)
    profile.addresses = profile_data.get('addresses', profile.addresses)
    profile.save()
```

It is working very well with user and profile I can create and update but when I add **addresses** it gives me error above shown in the title. I do not know yet how to solve nested inside nested relationships. Any help would be appreciated) Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 8):

Your issue is with this line

```
profile.addresses = profile_data.get('addresses', profile.addresses)
```

As the error message suggests, direct assignment to the reverse side of a relation is not allowed. What you want to do is use set() instead.

```
profile.addresses.set([list of new addresses])
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set

Comment: @jmp thanks for the answer but I do not know what to write. can you tell me please? If i write instances of Address model it says Address model got 'country' attribute

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same issue and this is how I fixed it.**

**Add an update method in your ProfileSerializer**

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
   address_data = validated_data.pop('address')
   instance.gender = validated_data.get('gender', instance.gender)
   instance.date_of_birth = validated_data.get('date_of_birth', instance.date_of_birth)
   instance.hometown = validated_data.get('hometown', instance.hometown)
   instance.phone = validated_data.get('phone', instance.phone)
   
   for address_d in address_data:
      Address.objects.update(profile=instance, **address_data)

   instance.save()
   return instance
```

**The update method of your UserSerializer should be:**

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
 profile_data = validated_data.pop('profile')
 instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
 instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
 instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
 
 for profile_d in profile_data:
     Profile.objects.update(user=instance, **profile_data)

 instance.save()
 return instance
```

**Based on your code, you're trying to update the address directly when updating your user yet there's no direct relation. Updating the user updates the profile. Updating the profile updates the address.**

Answer (score -2):

romoving this line may solve your problem:

```
profile.addresses = profile_data.get('addresses', profile.addresses)
```